# How to extract word from a string that may/may not start with a single quote

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Sample string:

```
'kernel-rt|kernel-alt|/kernel-' 'headers|xen|firmware|tools|python|utils'
```

`cut -d' ' -f 1 string.txt` gives me

```
'kernel-rt|kernel-alt|/kernel-'
```

But how do we proceed further to get just the 'kernel' from it?

Comment: Not clear, please do mention what are the conditions to grab the string in your post and let us know then

Comment: With GNU grep: `| grep -Po kernel` ;-)

Comment: You have three `kernel`s in your current output: which one do you want to get? If the first one, try `grep -oP "^'?\K[^\s-]+" file` / `grep -oP "^'?\K[^\s-]+" <<< "$s"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want only the 3rd **kernel** (in bold) and not the others

'kernel-rt|kernel-alt|/**kernel**-' 'headers|xen|firmware|tools|python|utils'

Here is how you extract it using single command `awk` (standard Linux `gawk`).

```
input="kernel-rt|kernel-alt|/kernel-' 'headers|xen|firmware|tools|python|utils"

echo $input|awk -F"|" '{split($3,a,"-");match(a[1],"[[:alnum:]]+",b);print b[0]}'
```

explanation

`-F"|"` specify field separator is `|` so that only is 3rd field required

`split($3,a,"-")` split 3rd field by `-`, left part assigned to `a[1]`

`match(a[1],"[[:alnum:]]+",b)` from `a[1]` extract sequence of alphanumeric string into `b[0]`

`print b[0]` output the matched string.

If you want to extract `kernel` from 2nd or 1st fields. Change `$3` to `$2` or `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
'kernel-rt|kernel-alt|/kernel-' 'headers|xen|firmware|tools|python|utils'
$
$ awk '{print $1}' file
'kernel-rt|kernel-alt|/kernel-'
$
$ awk '{gsub(/\047/,"",$1); print $1}' file
kernel-rt|kernel-alt|/kernel-
$
$ awk '{gsub(/\047/,""); split($1,f,/[|]/); print f[1]}' file
kernel-rt
```

and just to make you think...

```
$ awk '{gsub(/\047|\.*/,"")}1' file
kernel-rt
```